# Swift - Unexpected rows added to CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a CoreData base with 6 rows in it.

I na ViewController, the data is displayed in a UITable, when I select a row in the table, the didSelectRow
lists 6 rows. That are all the rows.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    caches = CoreData.getCaches()
    print ("Amount \(caches.count)") // gives 6

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Select", sender: nil)
}
```

When the Segue is executed the prepareForSegue is executed. Now the same command results with the value 7.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    caches = CoreData.getCaches()
    print ("Amount \(caches.count)") // gives 7
}
```

I suspect that something in the background is happening, but i can't find out what.
Below is the static method for reference:

```
static func getCaches() -> [Caches] {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var resultArray: [Caches] = []

    let request = NSFetchRequest<Caches>(entityName: "Caches")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    do {
        resultArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error - \(error)")
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't insert records. But why do you fetch the (same) data twice?

Comment: Perhaps add a print in getCaches to get count of `resultArray`

Comment: I’m fetching it twice because I found out that suddenly an extra row is inserted. It happens when the Segue is called and this proves that something strange happens.

Comment: Included a count with the same result

Comment: Some code  is inserting a row. Do you have any code that inserts rows? Set a breakpoint on that code

Comment: See the answer below. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found it.

I execute a performSegueWithIdentifier. Which calls the prepareForSegue in the calling ViewController. But apparently before that, the variables/properties from the called VC are created. (Which is logical if you give it some thought)

In the called VC, a variable was initialised with the following code
(copied from somewhere on the net)

```
var cache = Caches((context: (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext))
```

This line of ode was causing the trouble. Cause it creates an entity in the persistentContainer (not written to the actual CoreData). I replaced it with a plain old:

```
var cache = Caches()
```

And everything is working okay now. Thanks for the support.